# Twilio CLI setup; In autocomplete: What is "add the autocomplete env var to your bash profile and source it"?

Tags: twilio, command-line-interface

I'm following the CLI setup for twilio and i get the following instruction from the command line on my mac (mojave) when i reach the autocomplete section of this document (https://www.twilio.com/docs/twilio-cli/quickstart). I do not know what i am being instructed to do here. Excuse my naivety.

```html
1) Add the autocomplete env var to your bash profile and source it
$ printf "$(twilio autocomplete:script bash)" >> ~/.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc

NOTE: If your terminal starts as a login shell you may need to print the init script into ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile.

2) Test it out, e.g.:
$ twilio <TAB><TAB>                 # Command completion
$ twilio command --<TAB><TAB>       # Flag completion

Enjoy!
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run the command:

```
printf "$(twilio autocomplete:script bash)" >> ~/.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc
```

from your OS-X terminal prompt, it will then append `>>` the output of that command to your `~/.bashrc`file. It then sources the contents of that file to populate your terminal environment (do you don't need to close your terminal and re-open it in this first instance).

From that point on, when you start a new Bash shell, you will be good to go (and don't need to run that command again).